# How to open HTML pages of a document library in sharepoint in browser instead of downloading?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, html, browser-compatibility

There are some HTML files in our O365 SharePoint Online library. We want to open those files directly in browser instead of downloading.But there is no option in SP Online.Please suggest as we can only open aspx files directly not HTM.

Comment: Hi Adarsh,In SharePoint on premise server, we could set Browser File Handling to Permissive for users to open html files directly in the browser. But in SharePoint Online, there is no options for this. may be you can try to rename the file to .aspx file or use Page viewer to open these html file

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint on-premises, we can set Browser File Handling to Permissive for users to open html files directly in the browser. But in SharePoint Online, there is no options for this.

**Workaround:**

Rename the files, replace .html with .aspx. SharePoint Online will open .aspx in browser.

Comment: when renaming the html to aspx I get an error file not found.

Comment: Thanks, this method worked for us. We have some secure files that needed to be opened in a specific application and not in the browser. By creating .aspx files and using javascript, we are able to download the files and open them using the required application

Answer (score 1):

You can append "web=1" to the URL of your document so it will render in web view instead of letting your download the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page Viewer Web Part to display a Web page, file, or folder on a classic SharePoint page. You enter a hyperlink, file path, or folder path to link to the content.

**Notes**:

- You can use the Page Viewer Web Part only in a browser that supports
  the HTML IFRAME element.
- Displaying a file or a folder requires Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-a-web-page-folder-or-file-on-a-classic-sharepoint-page-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527).